# Error when trying to implement cast operator to nullable type in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, nullable, typecast-operator

I am currently creating a `struct Nullsafe<T>` that would wrap a reference type (hence `T:class`) and behave in a similar way to the `Nullable<T> struct`. The point is to emulate something close to what the `Option<T>` in F# does.

I intend to use the type in methods which I need to take special care of nulls. For example, assume I have a reference type `class Foo`, and the following code:

```
class Bar
{
    public void DoSomethingWithFoo(Nullsafe<Foo> foo);
}
```

Since I have created an implicit cast operator from `T` to `Nullsafe<T>`, then the below code would work fine:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();

Foo nullFoo = null;
bar.DoSomethingWithFoo(nullFoo);

Foo someFoo = new Foo();
bar.DoSomethingWithFoo(someFoo);
```

The `Nullsafe<T>` type is a struct (designed so on purpose, to eliminate passing any `null` values directly), therefore it is possible for someone to to write the below snippet:

```
Nullable<Nullsafe<Foo>> nullableNullsafeFoo = null;
// and later
bar.DoSomethingWithFoo(nullableNullsafeFoo);
```

The snippet, of cource, will not work.

So, I thought it would be a no-brainer to create a cast operator from within my `Nullsafe<T>` struct, which would handle nullable expressions like the above:

```
public static implicit operator Nullsafe<T>(Nullable<Nullsafe<T>> nv) => nv.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Unfortunately, this fails to compile. The compiler seems not to make a difference between the `Nullsafe<T>` and the `Nullable<Nullsafe<T>>` types, and throws at me the message:

Is the above a limitation of the compiler, or is it a purposedly intended behaviour? If so, are there any known workarounds?

> error CS0555: User-defined operator cannot take an object of the enclosing type and convert to an object of the enclosing type

I am using:

- Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.8.1
- .NET Sdk v2.1.400 (as shown by `dotnet --version`

The project is a library multi-targeting different .NET framework versions - from net20 to netstandard2.0

### Update

> Is the above a limitation of the compiler, or is it a purposedly intended behaviour?

It seems this is indeed a result of the compiler stripping type information, as described by fellow user [Isaac van Bakel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947247/isaac-van-bakel).

> If so, are there any known workarounds?

Doing as he adviced, I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29749) to the roslyn platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed behaviour is in fact intended [and confirmed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29749#issuecomment-419975665).

A language design [discussion thread](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1846) was created, to address whether this behaviour should be changed in favour of use-cases like the above, or to otherwise provide a better compiler error message to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if this is definitely intended, based on the code in [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/fab7134296816fc80019c60b0f5bef7400cf23ea/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Source/SourceUserDefinedOperatorSymbolBase.cs#L293). The behaviour comes from the compiler stripping the `Nullable` wrapper from the types involved in the cast in order to correctly catch identity casts from `Nullable<Foo>` to `Nullable<Foo>` - but in your case the types are different before the stripping, so it should be allowed.

You could open an issue in [the repository](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) - I couldn't find any already open. Someone more familiar with the design of the compiler would be able to weigh in, but it does seem like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, good to know this behavior is not **seemingly** inteded. I have submitted an issue as you advised and updated the question.